# Can't be import AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

In earlier project, With AFNetworking, I could either enable or disable web services log by `AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger`. But currently(2.0), I couldn't import `AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger`. How could I add this ?

Is Any other API instead of following?

```
[[AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger sharedLogger] startLogging];
[[AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger sharedLogger] setLevel:AFLoggerLevelDebug];
```

Please suggest new AFNetworking logger or some other else?

**Pod config:**

```
platform :ios, '6.0'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger) is now replaced with [`AFNetworkActivityLogger`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworkActivityLogger) in AFNetworking 2 and is  a separate pod:

```
platform :ios, '6.0'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'
pod 'AFNetworkActivityLogger'
```

Comment: Ya. I'll use it and let you know.

Answer (score 3):

`AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger` is deprecated with `AFNetworking 2.0`. Please use `AFNetworkActivityLogger` from now on.

For more detail please check this [link](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperationLogger/pull/21)